# Ajax post 404 error on server but localhost works

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, controller

In js I am trying to use post method. This is MVC Project.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/Page/FileUpload',
  data: formData,

  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function(data) {
    var result = JSON.parse(data);
    var arrStr = result.Result.split(/[;]/);

    if (result.Status !== 200) {

      console.log("beklenmedik bir hata oluştu");
      ui.hideDialog(self.$dialog);
      self.$dialog.remove();
      $("#mediatitle").val("");
      $("#mediaurl").val("");
      return;
    }

    if (arrStr[0] === "SUCCEED") {
      var ext = $('#mediaurl').val().split(".").pop().toLowerCase();

      if (ext == "pdf") {
        node = '<div class="bs-callout bs-callout-info" style="padding: 20px; margin: -5px 0px 20px; border-width: 1px 1px 1px 5px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(238, 238, 238) rgb(238, 238, 238) rgb(238, 238, 238) rgb(27, 128, 158); border-image: initial; border-radius: 3px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">' +
          '<a href="#" class="tzobPdfViewer" data-page="' + arrStr[2] + '" data-category="file" data-guid="' + arrStr[1] + '"><h4 id="callout-progress-csp" style="font-weight: 500; color: rgb(27, 128, 158); margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 5px; font-size: 18px;">' + fileName + '</h4></a>' +
          '</div></div>';
      } else {
        node = '<div class="bs-callout bs-callout-info" style="padding: 20px; margin: -5px 0px 20px; border-width: 1px 1px 1px 5px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(238, 238, 238) rgb(238, 238, 238) rgb(238, 238, 238) rgb(27, 128, 158); border-image: initial; border-radius: 3px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">' +
          '<a href="#" class="tzobFile" data-category="file" data-guid="' + arrStr[1] + '"><h4 id="callout-progress-csp" style="font-weight: 500; color: rgb(27, 128, 158); margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 5px; font-size: 18px;">' + fileName + '</h4></a>' +
          '</div></div>';
      }

      var a = context.invoke('editor.pasteHTML', node);
      ui.hideDialog(self.$dialog);
      self.$dialog.remove();
      $("#mediatitle").val("");
      $("#mediaurl").val("");
    } else {
      if (arrStr[0] === "NO_FILE") {
        console.log("beklenmedik bir hata oluştu");
        ui.hideDialog(self.$dialog);
        $("#mediatitle").val("");
        $("#mediaurl").val("");
        return;
      }

    }

  },
  error: function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log("beklenmedik bir hata oluştu");
    ui.hideDialog(self.$dialog);
    self.$dialog.remove();
    $("#mediatitle").val("");
    $("#mediaurl").val();
    return;
  },
  beforeSend: function() {

  },
  complete: function() {

  }
});
```

Code above is to post data and code below is controller.

```
public ActionResult FileUpload(Models.Media item) {
  if (item == null ||
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Title) ||
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Category))
    return Content(Serialization.JsonSerialize(new {
      Status = 400
    }));

  //if (Request.Files.Count <= 0 && string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Url))
  //    return Content(Serialization.JsonSerialize(new { Status = 401, Result = "NO_FILE" }));

  return Content(Serialization.JsonSerialize(new {
    Status = 200, Result = MediaRepository.AddFile(item)
  }));
}
```

The problem is that it returns a 404 error. I couldn't solve the problem. How can I solve it?

Comment: Shouting means?

Comment: Your caps lock got stuck ? All caps indicates shouting anywhere in the net

Comment: When asking for help, in addition to not shouting :-), please format the code in a reasonable way, so that the majority of it isn't hidden way off to the right.

Comment: can you mention the URL you are accessing from server as well as when you are accessing from localhost?